# Search string in dataframe based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Mark dataframe using string contains and dictionary

***INPUT:***

```
  a    b
0  x  abc
1  a    z
```

And a dictionary

```
columns = {'a':['abc'], 'b':['xyz', 'abc']}
```

I wanna do a string contains where string(values) are searched based on column(keys) in the dictionary.

I have implemented using for loop

***CODE:***

```
for col, strings in columns.items():
    df[col] = df[col].str.contains('|'.join(strings), case=False)
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
      a      b
0  False   True
1  False  False
```

How can I do this without a for loop and using dictionary directly?

Comment: There is no vectorized approach using strings in pandas. Also, str functions are applied only on Series. For performance, you can consider using list comprehension given the data is clean.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Thanks for the info. Could you answer how do I progress with list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` to speed up while working with `strings`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[True if value in columns[col] else False for value in df[col]] for col in df.columns]).T,
                  columns = df.columns)


print(df)
       a      b
0  False   True
1  False  False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Vishnudev Glad to help.